# Traversing with jQuery: cycle over children

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Hi all I have an html structure like this:

```
<tr>
    <td>
        <div class="sigle-sz">
            <span class="label-sz">36</span> <input class="" type="tel" value="" name="">
            <div class="available yes">
                <i aria-hidden="true" class="availablespot"></i>
            </div>
        </div> <!-- /sigle-sz -->
    </td>
    <td>
        <div class="sigle-sz">
            <span class="label-sz">38</span> <input class="" type="tel" value="" name="">
            <div class="available yes">
                <i aria-hidden="true" class="availablespot"></i>
            </div>
        </div> <!-- /sigle-sz -->
    </td>
    <td>
        <div class="sigle-sz">
            <span class="label-sz">40</span> <input class="" type="tel" value="" name="">
            <div class="available yes">
                <i aria-hidden="true" class="availablespot"></i>
            </div>
        </div> <!-- /sigle-sz -->
    </td>
</tr>
```

I created a jQuery function like this:

```
<script>
    function pippo() {

        //code here

    }

    $( document ).ready(function() {

        $( ".sigle-sz" ).on('change', function() {
            pippo();
        });
    });
</script>
```

I would, into the function "`pippo()`", cycle the `<td>` elements in the `<tr>` tag and save the input value in a variable.

If `this` is the `$( ".sigle-sz" )` element, how I can do this cycle?

I put here my current code: https://jsfiddle.net/ydrunbzz/

Comment: what do you mean by cycle , recursion or loop ? also what exactly you want to do ? can you show us what have you tried because writing function name does not count

Comment: I thought a for cycle, I don't know... if I up until the <tr> element, how can I for cycle the <td><input> elements?

Comment: _The onchange event occurs when a control loses the input focus and its value has been modified since gaining focus. This attribute applies to the following elements: INPUT, SELECT, and TEXTAREA._ So, `div.change()` is not going to help!

Comment: but the onchange event on the div works! I want only navigate into the children structure

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/ydrunbzz/

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$.each()` [jQuery function](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/):

```
var values;  // define global var to use everywhere

function pippo(myClass) {
    $.each(("." + myClass), function (index, value) {
        values += value;
    });
}
```

Comment: why global variable ? i dont think we should us global variable until we know exactly what we are doing. And in this case use of global variable is unnecessary

Comment: because he is calling `pipo()` function from `document.ready`, if he wants to use result in the event var must be global

Comment: What if he has other `.single-sz` elements outside of the current `<tr>` element?

Comment: Also, `$each` will return an `undefined is not a function` error.

Comment: @BenM if you want your answer marked as better than mine and not make a constructive dialog to help OP with his question, don't count with me. a) Thanks for the `$.each` correction. b) IMHO passing parameter would make code more unreadable and understandable for OP c) we have the HTML structure, so he is not suposed to have more `.single-sz` elements...

Comment: It's not about having an answer 'marked better', but I was just asking genuine questions (and am not the downvoter of your answer, by the way). Because he has posted a snippet of his HTML structure and not the full page, you can assume he does not have more `.single-sz` elements that are outside of the `<table>` container. Also, in case you revenge down-voted my answer, I'd be grateful of some explanation.

Comment: @BenM where you see it's a snippet? are you suposing by OP? cause question never said that.... You asking explanation of downvotes proves you search for punctuation and you don't concern "genuinely" about answering the question...

Comment: @JordiCastilla this is clearly a snippet, and not the full HTML structure. For example, why isn't the `<tr>` inside of a `<table>`?

Comment: yes this is a snippet. i have a table structure with many tr and td children inside

Comment: you need to iterate all `.single-sz` elements?

Answer (score 0):

Tonnes of ways to solve this with an .each() loop. I think it's important to have a very readable loop if you are new, or else you'll lose track fast.

1) global variable

2) first make sure that the data is gathered when someone writes something in the inputs!

3) the pippo function will clear the global variable "arrSigle" (short for Array Sigle), and make sure it's only filled with the current numbers written down

```
    $(document).ready(function () {

       //1
       var arrSigle= [];

       //2
       $( ".sigle-sz" ).find("input").on("change", function(){
            pippo();
//just FYI, the "change" only fires when an input has a new value, and lose focus
// by any means. If it annoys you to have to click out of the box for pippo()
//to run, you might want to use "onkeyup" instead of "change".
//it will fire every time someone lets go of a key while inside the input

       })

       //3
       function pippo(){
           arrSigle.length = 0; //this clears the variable
           $( ".sigle-sz" ).find("input").each(function(){
                arrSigle.push($(this).val()); 
                //this itterates over all the inputs and pushes them into the
                //global variable.
           })
           //If you want some function to run right after all the
           //numbers has been gathered, put it right under this comment.

       }
    });
```

We can all discuss how "efficient" this is, but considering how small your page probably is, i think it's more than justifiable to make it this  simple